# Copy input from one field and fill out another in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to make it where the user is able to drag their answer from a list of choices into four slots.

After the slots are filled, a form is to appear (ideally a reveal modal), which requires the user's first and last name and also displays their answer, which is the list of choices in order of which it is in the card slot.

I am having difficulty figuring on how to pass the value of the cards in the slots and their order to the "answer" field in the form.

Here is the code, it is both html and JavaScript

JavaScript:

```
var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

 //Hide the submit opttion

 $('#submitBox').hide();


 // Reset the game
 correctCards = 0;
 $('#cardPile').html( '' );
 $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

 // Create the pile of shuffled cards
 var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
 numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

 for ( var i=0; i<4; i++ ) {
   $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
  containment: '#content',
  stack: '#cardPile div',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
  } );
 }

 // Create the card slots
 var words = [ 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ];
 for ( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
  $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
  accept: '#cardPile div',
  hoverClass: 'hovered',
  drop: handleCardDrop
   } );
  }

  }

  function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
    var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
    var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

    // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
    // change the card colour, position it directly
    // on top of the slot

    if ( slotNumber != cardNumber ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );

    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 


   else{
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );

    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
   }


   // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
    // and reset the cards for another go


   if ( correctCards == 4 ) {      //Needs to be replaced with submit button and form fill out
   $('#submitBox').show();



     }

   }

   </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <body>

<div class="wideBox">
<h1>Wave Web App</h1>
<h2>Place the following waves in the correct order</h2>
</div>

<div id="content">

<div id="cardPile"> </div>
<div id="cardSlots"> </div>

<div id="submitBox">
    <a class="button" data-reveal-id="Submit">Submit</a>

    <div id="Submit" class="reveal"  data-reveal aria-labelledby="module1Title" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <form action="https://ww2.shsu.edu/mail04wp/formmail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
              <input type="hidden" value="4546" name="title"/>
              <input type="hidden" value="Fname, Lname" name="required">
              <input type="hidden"  value="http://www.shsu.edu/academics/continuing-education/completion-ceremony/thank-you-submission.html" name="redirect" id="redirect"/>



                   <p class="fhalf"><strong>First Name<br></strong><input id="Fname" name="Fname" type="text" required/>
                  <p class="lhalf"><strong>Last Name<br></strong><input id="Lname" name="Lname" type="text" required/>
                  <p class="fhalf"><strong>Your Answer</strong> <br> <input  id="answer" type="number" name="answer" value="cardSlots" disabled />

                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


          </form>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're running into? I'm not too keen on having to understand your entire use-case and current app (call me lazy) just to offer some general direction, but I (and others) would be more willing to chime in on a specific issue (that's easy for us to understand what you need help with)

Comment: Sure, basically the problem I am running into is finding how to gather the numbers of the cards put into the slots in their own order, and have it display within the "answer" field of the form in html
How to get the numbers of the cards in the javascript field to display in the form in the html field

Comment: If you can get a working demo on jsFiddle of what you're trying to do and why it's not working, that'd be great. I copied your HTML and JS over exactly, but I don't think it's doing what you described. Fix it up and let me know when it's recreating your problem https://jsfiddle.net/7tr7z6fa/#&togetherjs=12dAkC0HhC

Comment: actual maybe this link is all you need https://jsfiddle.net/7tr7z6fa/2/

Comment: I am fixing it up in the fiddle but cant find a way to put in the jquery scripts required for this to work

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: I'm pretty sure (I could be wrong) I already added the necessary jQuery references. On the top-right side of the screen, there's an "External Resources"  section where you can paste URL's to libraries your code needs. I already added jquery.min.js. Also - you may need to create an account with jsFiddle in order to edit it and share the updated version

Comment: btw - getting jsFiddle's to work, and being able to update and share one, is a great skill to use - especially for collaborating over the web on JS/HTML/CSS issues. So learning it is very worthwhile

Comment: I've updated it, for some reason the display is a little wonky, cards not confining to the box, but besides that, the rest of the program is up on the fiddle